# How to prevent custom view drawn with Path() from jumping when being resized?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I've created a custom view and I've drawn it's shape with Path().

```
class CurvedInvertedShape(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : RelativeLayout(context, attrs) {

    private var path: Path? = null
    private var paint: Paint? = null
    private var bottom: Float = 0f

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)

        paint = Paint()
        paint!!.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        paint!!.color = resources.getColor(R.color.light_gray, context.theme)
        path = Path()
        val horizontalOffset = w * .4f

        if (oldh == 0)
            bottom = h.toFloat()

        path!!.arcTo(
            -horizontalOffset,
            0f,
            w.toFloat() + horizontalOffset,
            bottom,
            180f,
            180f,
            false
        )
        path!!.lineTo(w.toFloat(), h.toFloat())
        path!!.lineTo(-horizontalOffset, h.toFloat())
        path!!.fillType = Path.FillType.INVERSE_EVEN_ODD
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        if (path != null)
            canvas.drawPath(path!!, paint!!)

        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }
}
```

My problem is when it's height changes, the bottom of the custom view jumps from one height to another, instead of smoothly resizing like other views would do.

Here is an example of how I'd like it to be and how it's actually performing : https://imgur.com/a/MZf9rnY

I'm pretty sure I need to do myself the animation since the view is made by me, but I can't find how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I don't know what I was thinking... Basically I created another view, which I set to match the layout where changes was made, instead of applying directly this custom view **for** the layout itself. Here are simplified examples :

```
<com.app.MyCustomView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_state_1"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_state_1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!--Some views which collapse and expands-->
</LinearLayout>
```

This above is what I had and didn't work and below is what I have and works :

```
<come.app.MyCustomView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_state_1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!--Some views which collapse and expands-->
</com.app.MyCustomView>
```

I can't believe I struggled so hard on this, knowing that I've done the same elsewhere on the same project. I suppose I was way to focus on doing the animation.